# Exchange empty cells for the number 0 in R

Tags: r

How do I exchange empty cells for the number 0 in my database below. I know it is possible to do: `df1[df1==""]<-0`, in this case it checks all columns in my database, however I would like it to be checked from the column `DR01`. I thought of something like this:
`df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0")=="")<-0`, but it didn't work.

```
df1 <- structure(
  list(Date = c("30-06-2021","01-07-2021","02-07-2021","03-07-2021"),
       DR1 = c(4,1,4,1),
       DR01 = c(4,1,4,2), DR02= c(4,2,6,2),DR03= c(9,5,4,2),
       DR04 = c(5,4,3,3),DR05 = c(5,4,5,""),
       DR06 = c(2,4,3,""),DR07 = c(2,5,4,""),
       DR08 = c(0,0,0,""),DR09 = c(0,0,0,""),DR010 = c(0,0,0,""),DR011 = c(4,0,0,""), 
       DR012 = c(0,0,0,""), DR013 = c(0,0,1,""), DR014 = c(0,0,0,"")),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

> df1
        Date DR1 DR01 DR02 DR03 DR04 DR05 DR06 DR07 DR08 DR09 DR010 DR011 DR012 DR013 DR014
1 30-06-2021   4    4    4    9    5    5    2    2    0    0     0     4     0     0     0
2 01-07-2021   1    1    2    5    4    4    4    5    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
3 02-07-2021   4    4    6    4    3    5    3    4    0    0     0     0     0     1     0
4 03-07-2021   1    2    2    2    3

> class(df1)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base solution:

```
df = structure(
  list(Date = c("30-06-2021","01-07-2021","02-07-2021","03-07-2021"),
       DR1 = c(4,1,4,1),
       DR01 = c(4,1,4,2), DR02= c(4,2,6,2),DR03= c(9,5,4,2),
       DR04 = c(5,4,3,3),DR05 = c(5,4,5,""),
       DR06 = c(2,4,3,""),DR07 = c(2,5,4,""),
       DR08 = c(0,0,0,""),DR09 = c(0,0,0,""),DR010 = c(0,0,0,""),DR011 = c(4,0,0,""), 
       DR012 = c(0,0,0,""), DR013 = c(0,0,1,""), DR014 = c(0,0,0,"")),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

# Select columns that will be modified
# save into variable, because we will use it a few times
selection = startsWith(names(df), "DR0")
df[selection][df[selection] == ""] = 0
```

Comment: @Antonio The only thing I can see is that in your example, the column names are starting with "DR0", but on the screenshot, they start with "Day"

If that doesn't help, try to do head(df1) and class(df1) and post the result.

Comment: @Antonio I see the problem. You don't have empty string `""` in your data. You have `NA`.

df[selection][ is.na(df[selection]) ] = 0 ` should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
df1[,-(1:2)][df1[,-(1:2)]==""] <- 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In `dplyr` you may use `across` -

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% mutate(across(starts_with('DR0'), ~replace(., . == '', 0)))

#        Date DR1 DR01 DR02 DR03 DR04 DR05 DR06 DR07 DR08 DR09 DR010 DR011 DR012 DR013 DR014
#1 30-06-2021   4    4    4    9    5    5    2    2    0    0     0     4     0     0     0
#2 01-07-2021   1    1    2    5    4    4    4    5    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
#3 02-07-2021   4    4    6    4    3    5    3    4    0    0     0     0     0     1     0
#4 03-07-2021   1    2    2    2    3    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
```